# Custom drawing commands on a specific pgfplots layer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw an extremely customized background grid, one that does not consist of lines extending all the way from one side of the plot to the other, and I want this grid to be drawn underneath the actual data plot.  I believe that the appropriate way to do this is to draw the grid as "custom annotations" (as the pgfplots manual uses that term) *on a specific layer of the plot*.  Complicating matters slightly, the data plot uses "fill between", which I understand to be somewhat troublesome.

I have been able to figure out how to move graphics drawn by `\addplot` to the "axis grid" layer, but not graphics drawn by TikZ primitives.  I need to use TikZ primitives because I need to use `calc` to make the lines extend outside the plot area by a specified *absolute* distance (to make them continuous with "outside" ticks; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/711879/pgfplots-precisely-align-custom-annotations-with-tick-lines) for why I can't just let pgfplots draw the ticks).

Concretely, this gets drawn underneath a "fill between":

```
\addplot[on layer=axis grid, draw=blue, no markers]
    coordinates {
        (10, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        (10, 0)
    }
;
```

But in this, the "on layer" bit has no effect and the line is drawn on top of the "fill between".

```
\begin{scope}[style={draw=red, /pgfplots/on layer=axis grid}]
\draw ($(20, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) - (0mm, 1mm)$) --
      (20, 0) ;
\end{scope}
```

What can I do to make `\draw` commands and the like be placed on a specific layer?

---

MWE follows. Rendered:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% The manual says compat=1.15 is the highest level that actually does anything.
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15, set layers}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0, xmax=30,
  ymin=-10, ymax=10,
  xtick={0, 10, 20, 30},
  ytick={-10, 0, 10},
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left,
  axis line style={draw=none},
  tick style={draw=none},
  clip=false
]
% This line is drawn underneath the "fill between" plot, as desired,
% but cannot be made to extend 1mm outside the plot area AFAICT.
\addplot[on layer=axis grid, draw=blue, no markers]
    coordinates {
        (10, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        (10, 0)
    }
;
% This line _can_ be made to extend 1mm outside the plot area, but
% despite the "on layer" key in the style, is drawn on top of the
% "fill between" plot.
\begin{scope}[style={draw=red, /pgfplots/on layer=axis grid}]
\draw ($(20, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) - (0mm, 1mm)$) --
      (20, 0) ;
\end{scope}
% I also tried this. The manual makes it sound like it should work,
% but it just produces a warning message ("the current plot has no
% coordinates") and draws nothing.
\addplot[on layer=axis grid, draw=magenta, no markers]
    coordinates {}
    ($(15, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) - (0mm, 1mm)$) --
      (15, 0) ;
\addplot[draw=none, no markers, name path=lower]
    coordinates { (0, -10) (30, 0) }
;
\addplot[draw=none, no markers, name path=upper]
    coordinates { (0, 10) (30, 0) }
;
\addplot[black] fill between [of=lower and upper] ;
\draw [draw=gray,very thin]
   (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
   (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Before trying to understand any of this, I want to know if you know the following: With `clip=false` `\addplot` most definitely can extend outside the axis area. You do not need `calc` to extend a line you can use `shorten >` and `shorten <` -see my previous answer. If you prefer, you can also use `xshift` and `yshift` on the coordinate - maybe even better. `on layer` can as far as know/remember not be used as option to `\addplot`.

Comment: Most important: things are drawn in the order they appear. Without understanding your use case or code, I do not see anything that needs layers!!

Comment: Why do you feel the need to attack me? I just asked clarifying questions and I just helped you with your previous question.

Comment: I don't understand. I only stated that I need an answer to the question I asked and not a workaround. No hostility was intended.

Comment: @JeT: If you feel for answering , then just go ahead. I often see something that is rude or I myself write something that can be read that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15, set layers}

\def\xmin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}
\def\xmax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}
\def\ymin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}
\def\ymax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0, xmax=30,
  ymin=-10, ymax=10,
  xtick={0, 10, 20, 30},
  ytick={-10, 0, 10},
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left,
  axis line style={draw=none},
  tick style={draw=none},
  clip=false
]
\addplot[on layer=axis grid, draw=blue, no markers]
    coordinates {
        (10, \ymin)
        (10, 0)
    }
;
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid}
\draw[style={draw=red}] ($(20, \ymin) - (0mm, 1mm)$) --
      (20, 0) ;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\addplot[draw=none, no markers, name path=lower]
    coordinates { (0, -10) (30, 0) }
;
\addplot[draw=none, no markers, name path=upper]
    coordinates { (0, 10) (30, 0) }
;
\addplot[black] fill between [of=lower and upper] ;
\draw [draw=gray,very thin]
   (\xmin, \ymin) --
   (\xmax, \ymin) ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @zwol is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: `\begin{pgfonlayer}` is indeed what I was looking for, thank you.